# FlowPlayer with Wowza

Tags: flowplayer, wowza

we're using flow player with Wowza. We've managed to get it so the stream starts on opening the page, however the stream is made up of several individual videos and between videos the user has to click play to resume the stream. Is there anyway to get flowplayer to automatically play the next video? Thanks
Dobro.

Comment: You need to add more details: what type of stream are you using (live, vod), is the playlist managed on the server (live stream with static files?) or in the client (player with JavaScript API) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the flash version of flowplayer (not the HTML5). Flowplayer offers a complete api, with events and properties to modify every aspect of the original configuration. For instance you could declare the 'onFinish' method in the clip, and then load another clip automatically

Check the flowplayer documentation: 
   http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/api/clip.html